# MeteorJS with a custom OAuth2 provider

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth-2.0, meteor-accounts

I have a custom OAuth2 server that I set up in Rails using Doorkeeper. It works great with my Rails apps and NodeJS/AngularJS apps. I pass an account ID and redirect URI to the server, it sends back a code, which I then send again to get a token with user information.

I am trying to find a guide or basic code I can alter to allow it to login with my own server. Unfortunately I can't find any guides for this or standalone OAuth2 packages for Meteor that have documentation.